# Kubuntu installer will not offer uefi option but did once

Tags: kubuntu, uefi, bootloader

Where to install boot loader. Kubuntu installer offered uefi...worked. Now after crssh on reinstalling only offers reserved BIOS area for grub but then won't boot - no drive shows

Answer (score 0):

The choice of BIOS-mode or EFI-mode installation is made by the way the installation medium is booted -- Ubuntu will install in BIOS mode if you boot the installer in BIOS mode and in EFI mode if you boot the installer in EFI mode. You can launch the installer by opening a terminal and typing `ubiquity -b` to install without a boot loader, but otherwise you really have no choice in the matter.

Thus, to control the installation mode, you must control the boot mode by using your firmware's tools. If you want to force an EFI-mode install, the best way is to disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy boot support" or a similar term) in your firmware setup utility. How this is done varies greatly from one computer to another, so I can't provide details. In some cases, you can force, or at least encourage, an EFI-mode boot even with the CSM enabled by using the computer's built-in boot manager. This tool will often provide two options for booting an external medium, one with the string "UEFI" and one without it. Selecting the "UEFI" option boots in EFI mode and the other option boots in BIOS mode. This isn't always 100% reliable, though.

Also, be sure your boot medium is prepared correctly. There must be at least half a dozen tools you can use to prepare a bootable USB drive from a `.iso` file, and some of them omit the EFI boot loader or otherwise prepare the USB drive in a way that will cause problems for at least some EFIs. Thus, if you can't seem to get a particular USB drive to boot in EFI mode, you may need to try another tool, or at least try other options within the tool you're using.